# How does a host machine resolve a network domain name?

Tags: networking, tcp, ip

Got a test coming up, cannot for the life of me answer this:

How does a host machine resolve a network domain name (convert domain name to IP address)? For example, if the host is on a network (users.company.com), and wants to convert the domain name "cdrom.com", what sequence of steps is used?

EDIT: Only skeptical of the DNS answer because it is literally no where in my instructors slides and recorded lectures.

Comment: DNS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it searches for a DNS server and then makes a lookup.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System